# can't find react native prompt in node modules

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have installed `react-native-prompt`. 
I can see that it has been added to `package.json`, but I can't find it on `node_modules` -- there is no `react-native-prompt` directory in `node_modules`. When I try to import `react-native-prompt`, it says that undefined is not an object. This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Prompt from 'react-native-prompt';

const AddTaskPrompt = ({isVisible,onCancelCallBack,onSubmitCallBack}) => (
<Prompt
    title="ajouter une tache"
    placeholder="ex: ramenre du lait"
    defaultValue=""
    visible={isVisible}
    onCancel={() => onCancelCallBack()}
    onSubmit={value => onSubmitCallBack(value)} />
);
export default AddTaskPrompt;
```

and the content of my `package.json` looks like

```
{
  "name": "fekri4",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "23.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.8.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^23.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.50.3",
    "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.18.5",
    "react-native-modal": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-prompt": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you `npm i`?

Comment: npm i it gives : no description , no repository field , no licence field

Comment: What does your package.json look like?

Comment: i've edited my post here is the content of my package

Comment: Can we see the full console output for when you ran "npm i"?

Comment: this is the full console C:\Users\x\fekri4>npm i
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.1.1 (node_modules\
ne\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevent
1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64
)

Comment: Did you try removing `node_modules` and installing everything again? `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`. Make sure to only run that inside your project directory!

Comment: yes i did , i removed node_modules and installed every thing again , using the same commande line in workspace folder , but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably doesn't fix your problem, but it does verify that `npm` and `react-native-prompt` works as expected. Plus, it's the only way I could share the image to prove it.

Here's how I tested.

1. `$ mkdir npm-test && cd npm-test`
2. `$ npm init -y`
3. `$ npm install react-native-prompt`

Works fine in this case. One thought is that you may have installed the package globally before. I'm not sure if npm is smart enough to say, "hey, I already have this globally, so I won't bother creating it locally too in this case". Just a thought.

[image]